# SQLParameter not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to access a stored procedure and I'm getting an error that says:

> Procedure or function 'getbug' expects parameter '@bugID', which was not supplied.

This is my code to call the procedure.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getbug", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("bugID", bugID));
```

bugID is set as 1089 (and is type int)

I can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: Just to note, adding "@" to the param doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If adding @ doesn't work can you show us some more code. The way you are doing it *should* work

Comment: Ahh, does adding cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure work? I think it defaults to .Text

Comment: WINNER!
Can't accept it as an answer though without you putting it as an answer.
:P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getbug", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bugID", bugID));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the "@" to the parameter

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getbug", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bugID", bugID));
```

Answer (score 1):

More code will help. Here's a couple of ideas though.

If you're calling a stored procedure, you need to specify the `CommandType`. Also, you can use the `AddWithValue` method to shorten your code.

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("getbug", cn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bugID", bugID);

        //etc...
    }
}
```